Why Serilog file suddenly doesn't write to file when reached 1000kb?
Here is the config
{
  "Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": [
      { 
        "Name": "File", 
        "Args": { 
          "path": "log.txt", 
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "shared": true, 
          "retainedFileCountLimit": null 
          } 
      }
    ]
  }
}

at the beginning, it works perfectly fine. However, once the file size reached around 1000kb, it stopped logging to the file.

Serilog has a default max file size, though from the documentation it should be 1GB by default, not 1MB. (https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file) See fileSizeLimitBytes to adjust this in case yours is set smaller somewhere or you are hitting the 1GB length and want larger. The limit can be removed by setting it explicitly to #null.

This issue with Serilog stopping logging to the file after reaching around 1000 KB could be related to file size limits or other underlying issues in the logging configuration. However, the configuration you've provided doesn't explicitly set a file size limit, so it should not stop logging based on file size alone. Here two options you could try,

Explicitly set SizeLimit field



Enable Serilog's self-log to see if there are any internal errors, you can add this just before Serilog is configured and logging begins or any where you're configuring your serilog.



Please convert the images to code, so it can be copy/pasted.
